# Query DbContext with Linq conditions and async

Tags: asp.net, linq, dbcontext

so I have a line of code as such:

```
Portfolio portfolio = await _dbContext.Portfolios.FindAsync(id);
```

But I only want portfolios that have their `IsDeleted` value set to `false`.

And I need it to be async, so something like this :

Portfolio portfolio = await _dbContext.Portfolios.FindAsync(id).Where(p => p.IsDeleted == false);

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this, what you are looking for.

```
Portfolio portfolio = await _dbContext.Portfolios.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id &&  IsDeleted == false);
```

If you are looking for list of portfolio that you will do it like this

```
List<Portfolio> portfolios = await _dbContext.Portfolios.Where(p => p.Id &&  IsDeleted == false).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it was, Thank you!  Accepted your answer.